# Adobe Indesign CS4 XML Import Problem(Missing Elements After Import)

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting, xml

I have been troubleshooting this problem for hours now. It's quite puzzling since a few hours back this did not happen at all. So I have completed placing the tags on individual text frame and was about to Import another xml. Basically all structures of the xml file are the same just the content of the tags are different.
Now after import all other element did update but are now gone from the drop down of the root.(please refer to the images) I am not an expert and have been reading now on the web for hours without luck. I hope someone here experienced this problem before and solved it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like those are currently unexpanded - click the little triangles and watch the magic!

Comment: yeah I already did that and the last 2 remaining elements are there and the rest are lost.

Comment: well yucky - so sorry. I've not seen this one before, I have to say.